# Different class for the last element in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I am creating a list using ng-repeat something like this

```
  <div ng-repeat="file in files">
   {{file.name}}
   </div>
```

But for the last element alone I would like to have a class (`<div class="last">test</div>`) included to it. how can i achieve this using ng-repeat?

Comment: was stuck on same from last 2 hour :)

Answer (score 251, accepted):

You can use `$last` variable within `ng-repeat` directive. Take a look at [doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angRepeat).

You can do it like this:

```
 <div ng-repeat="file in files" ng-class="computeCssClass($last)">
 {{file.name}}
 </div>
```

Where `computeCssClass` is function of `controller` which takes sole argument and returns `'last'` or `null`.

Or

```
  <div ng-repeat="file in files" ng-class="{'last':$last}">
  {{file.name}}
  </div>
```

Comment: i had a look at that earlier but couldnt figure out how exactly to use $last.. there aren't much examples out there either.

Comment: @Rahul, I've updated answer. Do you understand what I'm talking about?

Comment: yes.. I also got another answer from google groups  `<div ng-repeat="file in files" ng-class="{last: $last}">
       {{file.name}}
       </div>`

Comment: @Rahul, I guess, your answer is better than mine.

Comment: @Rahul, indeed sadly, it works for me. What do you have in developer console?

Comment: nothing.. there wasnt any errors but the class was not included for the div.

Comment: Searching for a "how to" on this methodology, I stumbled upon this SO question, and this answer was exactly what I needed! Thanks so much!

Comment: Would anyone have any ideas as to why $first and $last always return my list items as true however $index and $middle are working for me ?
I am using like this ng-class="{first:$first=true , last:$last=true}"
TY

[edit] oops was actually setting the value with = rather than == :)

Answer (score 23):

It's easier and cleaner to do it with CSS.

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="file in files" class="file">
  {{ file.name }}
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.file:last-of-type {
    color: #800;
}
```

[The `:last-of-type` selector is currently supported by 98% of browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=last-of-type)

Comment: Solution for AngularJS in CSS way 

Comment: NB: This does not work when `ng-repeat` is followed by `<div class="file"><!-- dummy for creating new element --></div>`, and you would like to set apart the list of existing _.file_ divs.

Comment: @DerMike In that case you'd put another class on the `ng-repeat` elements to differentiate them from the trailing `div`

Answer (score 14):

To elaborate on Paul's answer, this is the controller logic that coincides with the template code.

```
// HTML
<div class="row" ng-repeat="thing in things">
  <div class="well" ng-class="isLast($last)">
      <p>Data-driven {{thing.name}}</p>
  </div>
</div>

// CSS
.last { /* Desired Styles */}

// Controller
$scope.isLast = function(check) {
    var cssClass = check ? 'last' : null;
    return cssClass;
};
```

Its also worth noting that you really should avoid this solution if possible. By nature CSS can handle this, making a JS-based solution is unnecessary and non-performant. Unfortunately if you need to support IE8> this solution won't work for you ([see MDN support docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type)).

**CSS-Only Solution**

```
// Using the above example syntax
.row:last-of-type { /* Desired Style */ }
```

Comment: Note: CSS-only solution doesn't work if .ng-hide class is applied on the last element as :last-child doesn't concern itself with whether the element is rendered on screen or not, but whether it is literally the last element within the set in the markup.  http://fiddle.jshell.net/p5qe82w4/4/

Answer (score 8):

```
<div ng-repeat="file in files" ng-class="!$last ? 'class-for-last' : 'other'">
   {{file.name}}
</div>
```

That works for me! Good luck!

Comment: So if it's not $last, it has a class-for-last, and the last element has class other...

Answer (score 2):

You could use `limitTo` filter with `-1` for find the last element

***Example*** :

```
<div ng-repeat="friend in friends | limitTo: -1">
    {{friend.name}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by Fabian Perez worked for me, with a little change

Edited html is here:

`<div ng-repeat="file in files" ng-class="!$last ? 'other' : 'class-for-last'">
  {{file.name}}
</div>`