# Make borders for nonexistent spaces in table when using ng-repeat

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I'm trying to make a table in HTML using bootstrap. The table consists of 2 columns, the first being a string and the other being an array of strings. Each row has it's border but some rows don't have enough elements so that the border goes across the whole table. Here's a screenshot of what I mean ...

[image]

Notice how the lines seperating the rows get cut off when the data ends. How would I get the lines that separate the rows to stretch across the whole table? This is a snipet of my code

```
    <div style="overflow:auto; height:150px; width:75%; margin: 0 auto; margin-top:10px" ng-hide="show1">
<table class="table table-hover" style="width:auto">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th style="min-width: 150px">Family Members</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="name in names = (family | nameFilter: searchName)">
            <td style="min-width: 150px"><a ng-click="findMe(name.Name)">{{name.Name}}</a></td>
            <td style="min-width: 150px" ng-repeat="userName in name.User">{{userName.Name}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14581658/different-class-for-the-last-element-in-ng-repeat).  Then use that info to add a `colspan` with a very large number (say, 200) to the final `<td>` of the row.  That will make it expand to the length of the longest row in the table.

So your `<tbody>` will end up something like this:

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="xxx">First link</a></td>
    <td>Name 1</td>
    <td>Name 2</td>
    <td colspan="200">Name 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="xxx">Second link</a></td>
    <td>Name 1</td>
    <td colspan="200">Name 2</td>
  </tr>
  ...
</tbody>
```

Comment: Got it! Called the function from colspan so each element inside the array will have it's own "colspan" value

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that these should actually be table cells, but no matter.  You can create a function to calculate the longest list of usernames.

```
<td ng-repeat="i in new Array(longestList() - name.User.length)></td>
```