# Angularjs find last visible element in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I want to change the color of the last element in the list which is displayed as follows ,

```
 <div  ng-repeat="item in items">
<h3 ng-hide="(hideStudent && item.role == 'student')" ng-class="{'last':$last}">{{item.name}}</h3>
</div>
 <button type="button" ng-click="(hideStudent = true)" >Hide Students</button>
```

CSS:

```
.last {
color: #800;
 }
```

When I click on the "Hide Students" buttons then all students will be hiddden . Now if the last item is a student and its hidden then the last displayed element color is not getting changed because the $last does not seems to see if the element is hidden or not . I can use ng-if in place of ng-hide but wanted to know if this can be done in any other way rather than using ng-if.

Comment: This question is answered in [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14581658/4298824)

Comment: you can use only ng-style to define to show or to hide the item. And then, you can use :last-child to select last visible item: ng-style="(hideStudent && item.role == 'student') ? 'hide' : 'show'" and in css .show:last-child

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try use :last-child pseudo class
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Alast-child

Comment: I went on to do this by using css as you suggsted . thanks