# How to rename only one string from ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

Refer the below code, I am getting

```
0: {status: "DRAFT", $$hashKey: "object:282"}

1: {status: "SUBMITTED", $$hashKey: "object:283"}

2: {status: "APPROVED", $$hashKey: "object:284"}

3: {status: "REJECTED", $$hashKey: "object:285"}

4: {status: "RESUBMIT", $$hashKey: "object:286"}

5: {status: "APPROVAL_NR", $$hashKey: "object:287"}
length: 6
__proto__: Array(0)
```

as a response in "statusdata", I am using ng-repeat to display these data as a dropdown. I want to rename the last "approval_nr" in the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From angular docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat
You can use $last.

```
$last   boolean true if the repeated element is last in the iterator.
```

You can also check this one: [Different class for the last element in ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14581658/different-class-for-the-last-element-in-ng-repeat).
I would implement it like the following:

```
function renameIfLast(name, isLast) {
  if (isLast) {
    return name.toUpperCase(); // do you rename logic here <<
  } else {
    return name;
  }
}

<h1 ng-repeat="x in records">{{renameIfLast(x.status, $last)}}</h1>
```

Comment: I am looking not only to get the last value. I want to rename only last value in that list to some other name

Comment: `toUpperCase` is a function

Comment: @charlietfl too much scala I guess :)

Comment: @Varvarigos Emmanouil .. $last helped solving the issue. ThaNK you